# I used git add but I can't commit it

Tags: git

I modified my files and I used `git add .` to add them to staging area.

When I do `git commit -m "message"` it says that your branch is up-to-date and there are changes not staged to commit and can't commit and I did `git commit-a` too but didn't fix it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `iconBar/Site` is a nested git repository, possibly a submodule. You cannot commit it's changes from the outer repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i had the same issue. the problem is with the git index if i remember right.
close all git service or program relate and delete the .git folder from the repository. and add the origin again to the folder. it should show you the file that need to be stage. if it didnt help you try go to the origin repo and create this file and delete it.

i hope it help.

Comment: Deleting the `.git` folder sounds like a very bad idea. OP will loose his complete local history.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

`git add .`

use

`git add iconBar/Site`

and then

`git commit -m "message"`

Once commit is done, check git status:

`git status`

You must see `iconBar/Site` in green if your commit was successful. Once it is showing green, then you do git push.

`git push`

Hope this helps!